# How to compare or verify object that does not override equals method?

Tags: android, kotlin, mockk

I use mockk for unit testing in Kotlin (Android).

I want to verify that a function is called:

```
    verify { obj.callSomething("param1", Param2("A", "B")) }
```

In this case `Param2` is a generated Java class that doesn't override `equals` method so that the verification is always fail.

I've tried to use `match` but the failure message is simply not helpful.

```
    verify { obj.callSomething("param1", match { it.a == "A" && it.b == "B" }) }
```

Is there a better or correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `withArg` to run assertions and other arbitrary code on an argument in your verify call. Using `assertEquals` will give you better error messages.

```
verify {
  obj.callSomething("param1", withArg {
    assertEquals("A", it.a)
    assertEquals("B, it.b)
  })
}
```